# Fotos em divs diferentes usando instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, html, instagram-api

Estou a usar o instafeed.js API. queria que em vez de aparecerem todas as fotos na mesma div aparecesse uma por div. Tentei usar este exemplo mas não resultou: [exemplo instafeed.js em várias divs](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/12), criar várias instances do instafeed, uma para cada div. Alguma ideia?

instafeed:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed1',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'pizza',
    clientId: '*******',
    limit: 1
});

var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed2',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'pizza',
    clientId: '******',
    limit: 1
});

 var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed3',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'pizza',
    clientId: '******',
    limit: 1
});

 var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed4',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'pizza',
    clientId: '******',
    limit: 1
});

 var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed5',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'pizza',
    clientId: '******',
    limit: 1
});

 var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instafeed6',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'pizza',
    clientId: '******',
    limit: 1
});
instafeed1Feed.run();
instafeed2Feed.run();
instafeed3Feed.run();
instafeed4Feed.run();
instafeed5Feed.run();
instafeed6Feed.run();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="where1">
    <div></div>
    <div id="instafeed1"></div>
    <div id="instafeed2"></div>
    <div id="instafeed3"></div>
    <div id="instafeed4"></div>
</div>

<div id="where5">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="instafeed5"></div>
    <div id="instafeed6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No [site do plugin](http://instafeedjs.com) tem uma seção "Templating". Já tentou usar aquilo?

Comment: Não resulta, acho que não serve para isto

Comment: Desculpa @lucas, tu estavas certo. Obgado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É exatamente o que o [Lucas falou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35396/fotos-em-divs-diferentes-usando-instafeed-js#comment68681_35396), usar a [opção `template` do instafeed](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js#standard-options) e também a função `getMultipleTags()` postada na [*issue* linkada #12](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/12#issuecomment-20052294).

```
<style>
.insta-pic {
    background-color: #fcc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<h3>Rock Tag</h3>
    <div id="rockTag"></div>
<h3>Glass Tag</h3>
    <div id="glassTag"></div>
<h3>Wood Tag</h3>
    <div id="woodTag"></div>
<script>
function getMultipleTags (tags,client) {
    var feeds = [];
    for (var i=0, len=tags.length; i < len; i++) {
        feeds.push(new Instafeed({
            get: 'tagged',
            tagName: tags[i],
            target: tags[i] + "Tag",
            clientId: client,
            template: '<div class="insta-pic"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>'
        }));
    }
    return feeds;
}
var  client = 'NUMERO-ID';
if( client ) {
    // get multiple tags
    var myTags = getMultipleTags(['glass', 'wood', 'rock'],client);
    // run each instance
    for(var i=0, len=myTags.length; i < len; i++) {
        myTags[i].run();
    }
}
</script>
```

Demo no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/hm6cz4of/).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: E posso dar essa classe ('insta-pic'), a várias divs? A tag vai ser sempre a mesma, mas as divs é vão estar espalhadas pela página sem padrão nenhum em especial, uma foto por div.

Comment: Sim, pode. É só você brincar lá no JSFiddle até chegar ao resultado desejado.

Comment: Muito obgado, resultou

Comment: Só uma ultima coisa: eu queria que fosse sempre a mesma tag (pizza) nas 6 divs e não consigo porque o array 'myTags' não pode ter indexes iguais

Comment: Aí já é [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), Miguel ;)